# What's the difference between sync / async loading of Reality Composer files?

Tags: swift, realitykit, reality-composer

I saw the `synchronous` and `asynchronous` loading from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/loading-reality-composer-files-using-generated-code), but I am not understand about that. Could anyone explain the difference of them. Moreover, there is a caution:

> Use RealityKit’s synchronous loading methods from the main thread only. RealityKit throws a runtime exception if you attempt to use it from any other thread. If you need to load a scene on a background thread, use asynchronous loading instead.

What is the meaning of a main thread and background thread in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sync and async loading methods

If you click on `Experience.loadBox()` and select `Jump To Definition` command from context menu, you'll see the generated Reality Composer's code. This code has both `sync` and `async` loading methods. If your scene contains a "lightweight" model with a "lightweight" texture, use the synchronous `loadBox()` throwing method, which must be executed on the main thread.

In iOS, the `main dispatch queue` is a globally available `serial` queue executing tasks on the app's main thread. That means you can't run anything on that queue while the queue is busy. A serial queue can only use one thread at a time.

```
public static func loadBox() throws -> Experience.Box {
    guard let realityFileURL = Foundation.Bundle(for: Experience.Box.self).url(
                                                     forResource: "Experience", 
                                                     withExtension: "reality") 
    else {
        throw Experience.LoadRealityFileError.fileNotFound("Experience.reality")
    }

    let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent("Box", 
                                                     isDirectory: false)
    let anchorEntity = try Experience.Box.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
    return createBox(from: anchorEntity)
}
```

However, when RealityKit scene contains a model consisting of a large number of polygons with 4K textures, use the `loadBoxAsync()` method, which must be [concurrently](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/using-combine-for-your-app-s-asynchronous-code) executed on several background threads, to prevent ARView from freezing (i.e. not for executing a loading on the main thread).

```
public static func loadBoxAsync(completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<Experience.Box, Swift.Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let realityFileURL = Foundation.Bundle(for: Experience.Box.self).url(
                                                      forResource: "Experience", 
                                                      withExtension: "reality") 
    else {
        completion(.failure(Experience.LoadRealityFileError.fileNotFound("Experience.reality")))
        return
    }

    var cancellable: Combine.AnyCancellable?
    let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent("Box", 
                                                      isDirectory: false)
    let loadRequest = Experience.Box.loadAnchorAsync(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
    cancellable = loadRequest.sink(receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
        if case let .failure(error) = loadCompletion {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
        streams.removeAll { $0 === cancellable }
    }, receiveValue: { entity in
        completion(.success(Experience.createBox(from: entity)))
    })
    cancellable?.store(in: &streams)
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation! Since my RealityKit scene contains a large number of polygons model, do you have an example using `loadBoxAsync` on SwiftUI? Can I use the code in the topic of  **Load Reality Files Asyncronously Using Generated Code** given in the link?